# SQL Developer unit testing encoding fault

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've managed to configure our Oracle DB to run SQL Develper's unit tests. I've created a sample unit test, which needs to be able to use non-ASCII characters (for logging purposes). However, I've ran into a major obstacle. SQL Developer's unit tests seem to be unable to handle special characters.

I have a function that returns a NVARCHAR2 value (and contains special characters) and would like to use the following to test it:
[image]

When I click "Debug Implementation...", everything seems to work fine. But when I click "Run Test", I get the following:

```
Test Implementation 1 failed: Expected: [P????stup], Received: [Přístup]
Expected: [P????stup], Received: [Přístup]
Value: [91919]
```

And in the window I've shown above the text in "Result" also changes to P????stup.

In case it matters, my encoding in SQL Developer is set to Cp1250 (which for sure contains the problematic characters).

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a huge fail on Oracle's part?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Ok, I just found that even when I save and then hit refresh, I get P????stup.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do [Character Set Migration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96529/ch10.htm).